# ZenCart - Error Constant TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS already defined in

Tags: php, zen-cart, zen

I have a site was built by ZenCart. Everything is ok but this morning I get some errors message in my index.php like that

> Notice: Constant TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS already defined in
>   /public_html/includes/languages/english/index.php on line 35

I can't understand what I did before, Do you help me fix it.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the top of your script instead:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

The main downside of the above is that it will not get triggered if there is an error in your script prior to reaching it.

You could also stick the following in your `.htaccess` file

```
php_value display_errors 0
```

Alternatively you could solve the problem. Search for `TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS` and see where it is defined. The error indicates that is is being defined in at least 2 places, eliminate one (probably whichever is defined later) and the notice will stop appearing.

The likely reason for this suddenly appearing is a change in your host's installation of PHP. Before it didn't report Notices, now it does.

---

**edit**
If you still want to see serious errors (as a general rule turning off all errors is not a good idea) then use this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

It will only hide norices like the one you are seeing.

Comment: yes, I said "see not good" mean that :the main downside of the solution :"add error_reporting(0); at the begining of index.php file" is if my script have some error, it will not be dispayed

Comment: @tunghk_54 - See my edit above. It will show serious errors but hide notices.

Comment: @tunghk_54 - Glad it helped. Don't forget that SO normally works by the asker marking the best answer as "accepted" (by clicking the checkmark just underneath the vote up/down arrows).

Answer (score 0):

I put this line on top of index.php file
ini_set('display_errors',0);
but it see not good.